# Android Convert Unix Time to GMT time

Tags: android

I'm having trouble in converting a unix time into GMT.

I have the following code, but I would like to know how to vice versa it.

```
    public static String GetUnixTime() 
    { 
                 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                 long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); 

               return Long.toString(now);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Date d = new Date(1308670980000L);
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy,HH:mm");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String s = f.format(d);
```

Comment: You missed a bracket ")" before ";" (3rd line)

Answer (score 1):

long unixTime = unixTime;

java.util.Date GMTTime=new java.util.Date(unixTime);

System.out.println("GMTTime:: "+ GMTTime);

Comment: This give us date not time,how to get time.

Comment: You can get time by just changing SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:a") see Android document on SimpleDateFormat for more